# Is it possible to do this as a single efficient LINQ query?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, time-complexity

I have a class like

```
public class Foo
{
   public string X;
   public string Y;
   public int Z;
}
```

and the query I want to achieve is, given an `IEnumerable<Foo>` called `foos`,

> "Group by X, then by Y, and choose the the largest subgroup
>   from each supergroup; if there is a tie, choose the one with the
>   largest Z."

In other words, a not-so-compact solution would look like

```
var outer = foos.GroupBy(f => f.X);
foreach(var g1 in outer)
{
   var inner = g1.GroupBy(g2 => g2.Y);
   int maxCount = inner.Max(g3 => g3.Count());
   var winners = inner.Where(g4 => g4.Count() == maxCount));
   if(winners.Count() > 1)
   {
      yield return winners.MaxBy(w => w.Z);
   }
   else
   {
      yield return winners.Single();
   }
}
```

and a not-so-efficient solution would be like

```
from foo in foos
group foo by new { foo.X, foo.Y } into g
order by g.Key.X, g.Count(), g.Max(f => f.Z)
. . . // can't figure the rest out
```

but ideally I'd like both compact and efficient.

Comment: Just use code that *works* and that you *understand*. Don´t overcomplicate your code for the sake of any (estimated) effiency. The only thing I´d suggest is to avoid the double execution of the first query by calling `g1.GroupBy(...).ToList()`.

Comment: There is always a trade-off to consider in each solution. The not-so-compact solution could be efficient and readable, but the compact one could not be efficient or readable enough. I'd personally go with a not-so-compact, but efficient and readable solution. Even the most compact solution you could find could lead to performance issues or waste of time trying to understand it.

Comment: I don't think `w` has a `.Z`?

Answer (score 1):

you are reusing enumerables too much, that causes whole enumerable to be executed again which can cause significant performance decrease in some cases.

Your not so compact code can be simplified to this.

```
foreach (var byX in foos.GroupBy(f => f.X))
{
    yield return byX.GroupBy(f => f.Y, f => f, (_, byY) => byY.ToList())
                    .MaxBy(l => l.Count)
                    .MaxBy(f => f.Z);
}
```

Here is how it goes,

items are grouped by x, hence the variable is named `byX`, which means entire `byX` enumerable contains similar `X`'s.

Now you group this grouped items by `Y`. the variable named `byY` means that  entire `byY` enumerable contains similar `Y`'s that also have similar `X`'s

Finally you select largest list i.e `winners` (`MaxyBy(l => l.Count)`) and from winners you select item with highest `Z` (`MaxBy(f => f.Z)`).

The reason I used `byY.ToList()` was to prevent duplicate enumeration that otherwise would be caused by `Count()` and `MaxBy()`.

---

Alternatively you can change your entire iterator into single return statement.

```
return foos.GroupBy(f => f.X, f => f, (_, byX) => 
        byX.GroupBy(f => f.Y, f => f,(__, byY) => byY.ToList())
            .MaxBy(l => l.Count)
            .MaxBy(f => f.Z));
```

Comment: What you return is one item from the largest subgroup. But that is completely different behaviour. You should return the largest subgroup in principle (with some other rules when there is a tie).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the wording of your question I assume that you want the result to be an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo>>`. Elements are grouped by both `X` and `Y` so all elements in a specific inner sequence will have the same value for `X` and `Y`. Furthermore, every inner sequence will have different (unique) values for `X`.

Given the following data

```
X Y Z
-----
A p 1
A p 2
A q 1
A r 3
B p 1
B q 2
```

the resulting sequence of sequences should consist of two sequences (for `X = A` and `X = B`)

```
X Y Z
-----
A p 1
A p 2

X Y Z
-----
B q 2
```

You can get this result using the following LINQ expression:

```
var result = foos
    .GroupBy(
        outerFoo => outerFoo.X,
        (x, xFoos) => xFoos
            .GroupBy(
                innerFoo => innerFoo.Y,
                (y, yFoos) => yFoos)
            .OrderByDescending(yFoos => yFoos.Count())
            .ThenByDescending(yFoos => yFoos.Select(foo => foo.Z).Max())
            .First());
```

If you really care about performance you can most likely improve it at the cost of some complexity:

When picking the group with most elements or highest Z value two passes are performed over the elements in each group. First the elements are counted using `yFoos.Count()` and then the maximum Z value is computed using `yFoos.Select(foo => foo.Z).Max()`. However, you can do the same in one pass by using `Aggregate`.

Also, it is not necessary to sort all the groups to find the "largest" group. Instead a single pass over all the groups can be done to find the "largest" group again using `Aggregate`.

```
result = foos
    .GroupBy(
        outerFoo => outerFoo.X,
        (x, xFoos) => xFoos
            .GroupBy(
                innerFoo => innerFoo.Y,
                (y, yFoos) => new
                {
                    Foos = yFoos,
                    Aggregate = yFoos.Aggregate(
                        (Count: 0, MaxZ: int.MinValue),
                        (accumulator, foo) =>
                            (Count: accumulator.Count + 1,
                             MaxZ: Math.Max(accumulator.MaxZ, foo.Z)))
                })
            .Aggregate(
                new
                {
                    Foos = Enumerable.Empty<Foo>(),
                    Aggregate = (Count: 0, MaxZ: int.MinValue)
                },
                (accumulator, grouping) =>
                    grouping.Aggregate.Count > accumulator.Aggregate.Count
                        || grouping.Aggregate.Count == accumulator.Aggregate.Count
                            && grouping.Aggregate.MaxZ > accumulator.Aggregate.MaxZ
                        ? grouping : accumulator)
            .Foos);
```

I am using a `ValueTuple` as the accumulator in `Aggregate` as I expect that to have a good performance. However, if you really want to know you should measure.

Comment: Just realized my `orderby` answer is the same as yours but you could replace `.Select(foo => foo.Z).Max()` with `.Max(foo => foo.Z)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can prety much ignore the outer grouping and what is left is just a little advaced MaxBy, kind of alike a two parameter sorting. If you implement that, you would end up with something like:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Foo>> GetFoo2(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
{
    return foos.GroupBy(f => f.X)
               .Select(f => f.GroupBy(g => g.Y)
                             .MaxBy2(g => g.Count(), g => g.Max(m => m.Z)));
}
```

It is questionable how much you can call this linq approach, as you moved all the functionality into quite ordinary function. You can also implement the functionality with aggregate. There are two options. With seed and without seed. I like the latter option:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Foo>> GetFoo3(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
{
    return foos.GroupBy(f => f.X)
               .Select(f => f.GroupBy(g => g.Y)
                             .Aggregate((a, b) =>
                                    a.Count() > b.Count() ? a :
                                    a.Count() < b.Count() ? b :
                                    a.Max(m => m.Z) >= b.Max(m => m.Z) ? a : b
                             ));
}
```

The performance would suffer if Count() is not constant time, which is not guaranteed, but on my tests it worked fine. The variant with seed would be more complicated, but may be faster if done right.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this further, I realized your `orderby` could vastly simplify everything, still not sure it is that understandable.

```
var ans = foos.GroupBy(f => f.X, (_, gXfs) => gXfs.GroupBy(gXf => gXf.Y).Select(gXgYfs => gXgYfs.ToList())
                                                  .OrderByDescending(gXgYfs => gXgYfs.Count).ThenByDescending(gXgYfs => gXgYfs.Max(gXgYf => gXgYf.Z)).First());
```

While it is possible to do this in LINQ, I don't find it any more compact or understandable if you make it into one statement when using query comprehension syntax:

```
var ans = from foo in foos
          group foo by foo.X into foogX
          let foogYs = (from foo in foogX
                        group foo by foo.Y into rfoogY
                        select rfoogY)
          let maxYCount = foogYs.Max(y => y.Count())
          let foogYsmZ = from fooY in foogYs
                      where fooY.Count() == maxYCount
                      select new { maxZ = fooY.Max(f => f.Z), fooY = from f in fooY select f }
          let maxMaxZ = foogYsmZ.Max(y => y.maxZ)
          select (from foogY in foogYsmZ where foogY.maxZ == maxMaxZ select foogY.fooY).First();
```

If you are willing to use lambda syntax, some things become easier and shorter, though not necessarily more understandable:

```
var ans = from foogX in foos.GroupBy(f => f.X)
          let foogYs = foogX.GroupBy(f => f.Y)
          let maxYCount = foogYs.Max(foogY => foogY.Count())
          let foogYmCmZs = foogYs.Where(fooY => fooY.Count() == maxYCount).Select(fooY => new { maxZ = fooY.Max(f => f.Z), fooY })
          let maxMaxZ = foogYmCmZs.Max(foogYmZ => foogYmZ.maxZ)
          select foogYmCmZs.Where(foogYmZ => foogYmZ.maxZ == maxMaxZ).First().fooY.Select(y => y);
```

With lots of lambda syntax, you can go completely incomprehensible:

```
var ans = foos.GroupBy(f => f.X, (_, gXfs) => gXfs.GroupBy(gXf => gXf.Y).Select(gXgYf => new { fCount = gXgYf.Count(), maxZ = gXgYf.Max(f => f.Z), gXgYfs = gXgYf.Select(f => f) }))
              .Select(fC_mZ_gXgYfs_s => {
                  var maxfCount = fC_mZ_gXgYfs_s.Max(fC_mZ_gXgYfs => fC_mZ_gXgYfs.fCount);
                  var fC_mZ_gXgYfs_mCs = fC_mZ_gXgYfs_s.Where(fC_mZ_gXgYfs => fC_mZ_gXgYfs.fCount == maxfCount).ToList();
                  var maxMaxZ = fC_mZ_gXgYfs_mCs.Max(fC_mZ_gXgYfs => fC_mZ_gXgYfs.maxZ);
                  return fC_mZ_gXgYfs_mCs.Where(fC_mZ_gXgYfs => fC_mZ_gXgYfs.maxZ == maxMaxZ).First().gXgYfs;
              });
```

(I modified this third possiblity to reduce repetitive calculations and be more DRY, but that did make it a bit more verbose.)